Guy on the run in a car drives across country only to crash into a bulldozer and die
A movie probably from the 1970's where a guy is trying to make it across the country in a car while cops chase him across each state. I think he's trying to make it to some state where he might be safe from the law.
I also remember a radio DJ is sort of commenting on air as the guy on the lamb keeps evading the cops. I think the DJ is black and wears sunglasses, but not sure.
Major spoiler: The movie ends with the cops at the state line where they set up a huge blockade. They have bulldozers in each lane of the road and the guy on the run decides there is nothing else he can do so he crashes into the bulldozers at full speed dies. Movie over, credits run, one of the dumbest endings ever from what I recall.
I've never seen the beginning, but have seen the end twice back in the 90's sometime.

Sounds like the 1971 movie Vanishing Point.
Here's the description regarding the ending from Wikipedia

On Sunday morning, California police, who have been tracking Kowalski's movements on an electronic wall-map, set up a roadblock with two bulldozers in the small town of Cisco, where Kowalski will be passing. A small crowd gathers at the roadblock. As Kowalski approaches at high speed, he smiles as he crashes into the bulldozers in a fiery explosion. As firemen work to put out the flames, the crowd slowly disperses

Here's a link to the trailer on YouTube:




I agree, the OP seems to be describing this movie. The DJ is played by Cleavon Little and wears dark glasses because he's blind. The ending stuck with me because the opening shows Kowalski turning around before he hits the bulldozers.

wow, gotta see this movie... that trailer alone is loaded with classic lines. "He uses speed to get himself up... to get himself... GONE."

This has to be it! I was even thinking it was California he was driving towards and that the DJ was blind, but didn't want to taint the question with stuff I wasn't too sure about. Thanks!

Its this movie, Vanishing point. 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067927/?ref_=nv_sr_2
still very watchable

What does this add to the existing answer given 7 hours before this one?

Confirmation and encouragement that the original answer was correct. ;-)
